# Where to get rectangular coordinates of the solar system planets?

Tags: coordinates

Title, I tried converting the coordinates from [here](http://cosinekitty.com/solar_system.html) to rectangular but it seems off.

Comment: [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi).

Comment: err...could you tell me how? lol

Comment: Explore and learn.

Comment: I only see Heliocentric coordinates, no options for rectangular formats

Comment: Give us an example of the coordinates you used and the answer you came up with.

Comment: Using r as .3207197 AU, longitude as 118 degress and latitude as 6 degrees: -22401375658.9
-2354479457.53
42362928617.4 for x y z

Comment: Part of exploring is to click on all the Change links, and seeing what all of the options are.

Comment: You should edit your question to include this information. Adding some units to the answer would be helpful. Also information about the reference frames you are using.  The more information you provide, the more likely it is that someone will provide an answer.  Making people guess at what you mean makes it unlikely.

Comment: You could look at other questions here that have the `jpl-horizons` tag: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jpl-horizons and see if those give you some insight. See how far you can get by trying things yourself, and reading those questions and answers. The (or at least a) goal in stackexchange is to build a set of searchable questions and answers. Look around, and [take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) while you're at it.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of your linked web page is the sentence:

> If you need really accurate data for a planet or asteroid, try the [JPL HORIZONS](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons) System. (These guys were navigating spacecraft through the solar system when I was still playing with GI Joe!)

...which is indeed an excellent answer to your question!

A step-by-step example of how to obtain "rectangular coordinates of the solar system planets" using Horizons can be found in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25357/12102).

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a good live imagery of planetary positions. Also try this question in Astronomy SE.

http://www.astrosoftware.com/cpnew/software/sirius/features/skymap.html works well.

The examples in the question and the comments are valid ways to track the planets. I do see plausibility in converting the coordinates into a visual grid.