# Where can I find examples of orbital state vectors?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements

I'm currently trying to write a program that can calculate orbital trajectories. The goal is to take any orbital state vector (position, velocity) and convert it into Keplerian orbital elements, or convert Keplerian elements into an orbital state vector.

I would like to test out if my code works by getting examples of orbital state vectors and their corresponding Keplerian elements, so that I can plug them into my program to check if the output matches the correct output. However, I can't seem to find any examples of orbital state vectors and their corresponding Keplerian elements, after browsing the web I can only find descriptions of what orbital state vectors are with no examples.

Comment: Horizons: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi Also, read [these questions about Horizons](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=horizons)

Answer (score 4):

[JPL's Horizons web interface](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) is a great place to do this. See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25357/12102) for a detailed explanation of how to do it.

For planets and the Moon, you can use a little Python with the nifty [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) package locally. It loads the JPL ephemerides to your computer locally, and does roughly the same thing as Horizons does, interpolates to your requested time points.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for you.

State vectors on the left, orbital parameters on the right.

This is an old hardcopy from the Shuttle Mission Simulator.

[image]

I don't know a general answer.

Comment: What about [horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi)?

Comment: Sounds like you should post an answer!  I am not familiar with 'horizons' other than seeing it referenced on this site.

Comment: Check it out :). uhoh introduced me to it! It's honestly more of a comment to be honest; don't need points for posting a site link lol

Comment: fyi I've just asked [How were the geodetic and geocentric latitudes of the Space Shuttle defined and calculated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35623/12102)