# Are planet orbits available to download in some vectorial format file?

Tags: orbit, solar-system, simulation

I would like to work with solar system planet orbits in a Geographic Information Software like QGIS, so:

Are available to download the orbits of solar system planets in some vector format?

EDIT:

Specifically, I would like to see planet orbits scaled to the size of a city, similar to the video below, but adding the planet orbits to a map in a tool like QGIS, to be able to play with scale, planets positions, etc..

Comment: There are a lot of different resources described in answers to [Where can I find/visualize planets/stars/moons/etc positions?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982) (in Astronomy Stack Exchange) The two I use are JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) website and the Python package [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/). Either will give you state vectors (x, y, z, vx, vy, vz) for solar system objects in several solar-system and Earth based coordinate systems.

Comment: Here's a short [tutorial](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25357/12102) for the Horizons interface. If you add more specifics to your question those may be answerable as well.

Comment: Thanks @uhoh for the references. As you suggested, I have added more specifics to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways you can get this information, depending on exactly what you want.

[Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) is a good way to just get the relative positions of the planets. You can query it, download a set, and get the data you need via that tool pretty easily. If you have a limited range of time scales for this, that is probably your best bet.

If you want a more long term system, or more accurate, I suggest downloading the planet spice kernels and generating the data locally. There are a number of libraries which read SPICE kernels, I know of at least one for C and Python. Looking at it, it seems Fortran, IDL, Java, and Matlab are also options. You can read all about it at the [NASA NAIF website](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/spiceconcept.html), and get the kernels specifically from [this page](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data_generic.html).