# How could one determine the acceleration of a satellite given its ephemeris data, taking into account the earth's oblateness?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I am looking to determine the acceleration vector of a satellite orbiting the earth at a certain point in time given its ephemeris data for that same point in time. I am taking into account the effects of an oblate earth, but not of third-body forces, aerodynamic forces, or solar radiation pressure.

To find the ephemeris data for a satellite, I use JPL's HORIZONS Web-Interface (https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), and I use the VECTORS ephemeris type, which gives me the following information for a given point in time (key included as well): (I apologize for including this information for anyone that is already familiar with this tool, as I only wanted to make the data format I am working with more accessible)

```
Information given for one point in time:
JDTDB
X     Y     Z
VX    VY    VZ
LT    RG    RR

Key (units can be changed):
JDTDB    Julian Day Number, Barycentric Dynamical Time
  X      X-component of position vector (au)
  Y      Y-component of position vector (au)
  Z      Z-component of position vector (au)
  VX     X-component of velocity vector (au/day)                           
  VY     Y-component of velocity vector (au/day)                           
  VZ     Z-component of velocity vector (au/day)                           
  LT     One-way down-leg Newtonian light-time (day)
  RG     Range; distance from coordinate center (au)
  RR     Range-rate; radial velocity wrt coord. center (au/day)
```

How would I solve for the acceleration vector given this information?

I know that assuming a spherical earth, the magnitude of the acceleration is given by

```
|Ā| = GM / R^2 (where R is the distance between the satellite and the center of the earth),
```

but would that work for an oblate earth? In addition how can I determine the direction of the vector? Assuming a spherical earth, the direction of the acceleration vector would be opposite to that of the position vector, but I do not think that would work either.

I appreciate the help! Also, if my problem is beyond the scope of a StackExchange question, I would appreciate references to source material that I could look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Units

I aways use kilograms, meters and seconds ([MKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_system_of_units)) to avoid getting tripped up by mixed units. Horizons offers both `AU & AU/day` and `km & km/sec` options and the first thing I do when importing ephemeris data is convert the `km & km/sec` to `m & m/sec`!

[image: some settings in JPL's Horizons]

This is from [this JPL Horizons tutorial](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25357/12102)

### Central force ("monopole term")

The main term in the spherical harmonic expansion of Earth's gravity that's associated with oblateness is called $J_2$. It's the second term, the first term is the central force "the main gravity" that I also call the monopole term.

> The acceleration of a body in the gravitation field of another body of [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) $GM$ can be written:
>
> $$\mathbf{a_{Central}} = -GM \frac{\mathbf{r}}{|r|^3},$$
>
> where $r$ is the vector from the body $M$ to the body who's acceleration is being calculated. Remember that the acceleration of each body depends only on the mass of *the other body*, even though the force depends on both masses, because the first mass cancels out by $a=F/m$.

Written out as components that would be

> $$\mathbf{a_{Central}} = -GM \frac{x}{|r|^3}\mathbf{\hat{x}} -GM \frac{y}{|r|^3}\mathbf{\hat{y}} -GM \frac{z}{|r|^3}\mathbf{\hat{z}}$$

In Python I write:

```
a = -GM * X * np.sqrt((X**2).sum())**-1.5
```

where `X` is a position vector.

This is from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102) to *How to calculate the planets and moons beyond Newtons's gravitational force?* as is the quote below

> **Oblateness ($J_2$ only):**
>
> I'm just using the math from [Wikipedia's article on the Geopotential Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_model#The_deviations_of_Earth.27s_gravitational_field_from_that_of_a_homogeneous_sphere) with a very important-to-remember approximation; I am assuming that the oblateness is in the plane of the ecliptic — that the rotational axis of the oblate body is in the $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ direction, perpendicular to the ecliptic. **Don't forget that this is an approximation!** [...]
>
> $$\mathbf{r} = x \mathbf{\hat{x}} + y \mathbf{\hat{y}} + z \mathbf{\hat{z}} $$
>
> $$a_x = J_2 \frac{x}{|r|^7} (6z^2 - 1.5(x^2+y^2)) $$
>
> $$a_y = J_2 \frac{y}{|r|^7} (6z^2 - 1.5(x^2+y^2)) $$
>
> $$a_z = J_2 \frac{z}{|r|^7} (3z^2 - 4.5(x^2+y^2)) $$
>
> The following should be *added to* the <s>Newtonian</s> monopole term:
>
> $$\mathbf{a_{J2}} = a_x \mathbf{\hat{x}} + a_y \mathbf{\hat{y}} + a_z \mathbf{\hat{z}} $$

Unless you are doing very precise work, it's probably safe to assume that the oblateness is in the plane of the ecliptic; that Earth's axis is still pointing in the same direction that it was in the year 2000. [It does slowly precess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession) but how to deal with that mathematically is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: so just to be clear, **Total_Acceleration** = **A_Newton** + **A_J2**?

Comment: @Steven oh I should call it "Central" since we're not talking about non-Newtonian forces here. Yes those are the two main terms, and for low Earth orbit the second one is roughly 1/1000 as large as the first one. There are higher order multipoles (even for Earth's oblateness) but they are much much smaller.